# class not found exception in eclipse even though the user library containg jar file is in java build path

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, classpath, buildpath

I have created a dynamic web project. A user library with a jar file is also created.

Then the user library has been added to the build path via 
project properties--->java build path--->In libraries tab required user library has added and jar file is specified under it.

But exporting the project into the JBoss deployment directory is raising class not found exception over the class in added jar file.

How can I properly add a user library to my project's build path?

Comment: It's not clear what your are doing, sorry. But If you create a War Package (default for webprofile webapplications) you have to place your libraries inside your package at WEB-INF/lib/ then they are added by the app server into your apps classpath

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.But I have already tried with the solution that you have suggested.Everything is working fine when the corresponding jar is in WEB-INF/lib.What I am trying to do is that I have a folder lib in my project.Inside that folder one sub-folder is there.I want to put my jar file in that sub-folder.Then I have created a user library referencing the jar file in sub-folder.And added that user-lib in java build path of my project.But it is showing Class Not Found Exception

Comment: I dont understand this but it will not work. The app server will only load custom libariers for your app when they are in WEB-INF/lib. You sad you use Jboss, I think you mean JBOSS AS 7.x or Wildfly 8.x ? Correct? Then you can also create modules for the app server to place libraries. But then you have to provide a custom jboss deploy structure file to allow the app server to inject modules to your classpath.

Comment: JBOSS AS 7.1 is using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not clearly understand your problem but there is nothing to discuss ;)
Because the Java EE Specifications and the application server are dictating how to place something in your app's classpath and that's it.

Here is the documentation:
https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Class+Loading+in+AS7

If your problem is not regarding the result on the appserver, only something about comfor or project strcture you want in your IDE. Then use your build system (Maven) to do the job. Like bilding a jar and coping it to desired location etc.